# ThreadPoolExecutor is leaking memory

Tags: python, memory-leaks, threadpoolexecutor, concurrent.futures

I'm using a ThreadPoolExecutor and I don't understand why it is leaking memory:

```py
def callback(message):
    # Memory intensive operation
    x = [n for n in range(int(1e6))]
    return message
    
@profile
def main():
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        executor.map(callback, [x for x in range(10)])
    time.sleep(2)
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        executor.map(callback, [x for x in range(10)])
    time.sleep(2)
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        executor.map(callback, [x for x in range(10)])
    time.sleep(2)
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        executor.map(callback, [x for x in range(10)])
    time.sleep(2)
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        executor.map(callback, [x for x in range(10)])
    time.sleep(2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Produces this graph
[image]

What is going, exactly? This does not happen if I run this code synchronously.

Comment: that does not means at all there are memory leaks, you do not know when the garbage works and then what amount of memory is still used when it finish each time. Just do in a loop (rather than copy paste a given number of times) with different number of times even large and look at the used memory at the end of the loop before to exit and you will see the  size of the used memory does not grow with the number of loop

Comment: I tried, and it grows. I also tried to force garbage collection with gc.collect() at the end of every iteration and it doesn't change. Can I ask you if you really tried what you're saying? And how, in that case?

Comment: Same issue here. Super annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer to your remark *Can I ask you if you really tried what you're saying? And how, in that case?*

I test with that program :

```
import concurrent.futures
import time,sys,os,gc

def callback(message):
    # Memory intensive operation
    x = [n for n in range(int(1e6))]
    return message
    
def main():
    delay = int(sys.argv[2])
    for _ in range(0, int(sys.argv[1])):
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
            executor.map(callback, [x for x in range(10)])
        time.sleep(delay)
    gc.collect()
    os.system("ps l -C python3")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

some executions when sleeping 0 sec each time :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ python3 p.py 1 0
F   UID   PID  PPID PRI  NI    VSZ   RSS WCHAN  STAT TTY        TIME COMMAND
0  1000 16784  2657  20   0  57616 11840 do_wai S+   pts/0      0:01 python3 p.py 1 0
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ python3 p.py 2 0
F   UID   PID  PPID PRI  NI    VSZ   RSS WCHAN  STAT TTY        TIME COMMAND
0  1000 16811  2657  20   0  57872 12100 do_wai S+   pts/0      0:03 python3 p.py 2 0
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ python3 p.py 10 0
F   UID   PID  PPID PRI  NI    VSZ   RSS WCHAN  STAT TTY        TIME COMMAND
0  1000 16835  2657  20   0  58412 12760 do_wai S+   pts/0      0:18 python3 p.py 10 0
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ python3 p.py 20 0
F   UID   PID  PPID PRI  NI    VSZ   RSS WCHAN  STAT TTY        TIME COMMAND
0  1000 16950  2657  20   0  58924 13240 do_wai S+   pts/0      0:35 python3 p.py 20 0
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ python3 p.py 100 0
F   UID   PID  PPID PRI  NI    VSZ   RSS WCHAN  STAT TTY        TIME COMMAND
0  1000 17179  2657  20   0  57900 12320 do_wai S+   pts/0      2:58 python3 p.py 100 0
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

as you can see the size after 100 turns is smaller than after 10 and 20

Now if I wait 1 sec each turn the results are different and smaller or equal than previously :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ python3 p.py 1 1
F   UID   PID  PPID PRI  NI    VSZ   RSS WCHAN  STAT TTY        TIME COMMAND
0  1000 18251  2657  20   0  57360 11708 do_wai S+   pts/0      0:01 python3 p.py 1 1
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ python3 p.py 2 1
F   UID   PID  PPID PRI  NI    VSZ   RSS WCHAN  STAT TTY        TIME COMMAND
0  1000 18276  2657  20   0  57616 11840 do_wai S+   pts/0      0:03 python3 p.py 2 1
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ python3 p.py 10 1
F   UID   PID  PPID PRI  NI    VSZ   RSS WCHAN  STAT TTY        TIME COMMAND
0  1000 18299  2657  20   0  58412 12748 do_wai S+   pts/0      0:17 python3 p.py 10 1
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ python3 p.py 20 1
F   UID   PID  PPID PRI  NI    VSZ   RSS WCHAN  STAT TTY        TIME COMMAND
0  1000 18417  2657  20   0  58412 12824 do_wai S+   pts/0      0:34 python3 p.py 20 1
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ python3 p.py 100 1
F   UID   PID  PPID PRI  NI    VSZ   RSS WCHAN  STAT TTY        TIME COMMAND
0  1000 20469  2657  20   0  57900 12328 do_wai S+   pts/0      3:13 python3 p.py 100 1
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

for the python point of view that as no sense, may be the variability does not come (only) from Python but (also) the time Linux needs to manage the threads disappearance. Of course if you do all synchronously you do not have that problem

I did on a PI4 :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 5.10.17-v7l+ #1403 SMP Mon Feb 22 11:33:35 GMT 2021 armv7l GNU/Linux
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ python3 --version
Python 3.7.3
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

You can see also in your diagram the last 3 lower levels are equal (like valuing 100) and this is not compatible with memory leaks or at least visible ones

Comment: Thank you.
Just tried your example and seeing the same results. So it is just a strange behavior...
I didn't expect that the sleep time between executors could "interfere" at os level.

Comment: @MilesDavis yes I was surprised too, the memory/thread management is not simple to understand, note also the measurement (*ps* or other way) does what it can too